# python DataFrame data export to stata using to_stata() raise ValueError

Tags: pandas

I use to_stata() to exporting my DataFrame

```
AppliedTariff.to_stata('Applied%s.dta' % name, write_index = False)
```

raise ValueError('Writing general object arrays is not supported')

I do not know how to continue.

Comment: when I use to_csv() to do this, it works ok. but I want to obain the dta version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the answer via this [link](https://www.maxmasnick.com/projects/scipy-tips/).

Find out which columns are of the `object` type:

```
list(df.select_dtypes(include=['object']).columns)
```

Convert them to something else: `df['col'] = df['col'].astype(str)`